# Get a remote computers IP address and name in VB

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am fairly new to Visual Basic programming and I have just started with programming lately. So i am kind of Programming dummy.

I would like to know , if it is possible to read the IP address and Machine's name of others computer using any Visual Basic code?

Basically PC 1 and PC 2 are connected via Ethernet cable.

By clicking a 'button' in the application window, it must be able to show the IP address and the name of the other machine.

Hope some kind people can advice on this with a 'how-to'.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Scan the entire subnet your machine is on looking for a response from the other machine.
2. Have a program on the other machine broadcasting its address and name